# swift table view is locked when searchbar active

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

i'm using a large navigation bar which includes a searchcontroller. If i dont search i can scroll through my tableview without problems, but if i'm searching it seams like its locked. Here is my code:

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

    // First we will check if input is only containing numbers => search for PLZ otherwise we will check if a restaurant is called like this otherwise search if there is a suitable city
    self.navigationItem.title = searchController.searchBar.text!

if !searchController.isActive{
        //TODO get all restaurants for default city
    self.navigationItem.title = "München"

    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "partnerscell", for: indexPath) as! PartnersCellTableViewCell

    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    var bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
    var width = bounds.size.width
    var height = bounds.size.height
    return height/2.2
}

@IBOutlet weak var tv: UITableView!
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
            searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
 if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
             self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    }

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true

    self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
}
```

Also if i'm searching my toolbar looks darker. Please find attached two screenshots:[image: Searchbar is not active, scrolling is possible]

[image: Searchbar is active, scrolling impossible]

Comment: Why your `tv` wasn't assigned `delegate` and `dataSource`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not access tableview when your search is active because attribute of `UISearchController` `obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation` is default true which indicating underlying content of controller is obscured when search is active. So you can set as follow:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
            searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
 if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
             self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    }

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true

    self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.definesPresentationContext = true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't access the table view, because there is an invisible layer over it caused by wrong configuration of `UISearchController`.
Modify the `searchController` this way:

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
searchController.definesPresentationContext = true
```